# Avoid http-equiv <meta> tags

Tags: character-encoding, http-headers, mime-types, meta-tags, http-equiv

can be avoid
 `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`
and replace this by `<meta charset="utf-8">`

and what is the best replacement for `<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">`

My concern is to remove `http-equiv <meta>`  tags